# Change height of multiple textinput according to content separately javascript react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have created a question array set dynamically in which it has multiple textinput fields and i want to change height of the text input when the content size increases.

```
const[height,setHeight]=useState(44)
```

But i have multiple text input with multiline option

```
<TextInput multiline height={height} placeholderText={'Question 1'}/>
<TextInput multiline height={height} placeholderText={'Question 2'}/>
<TextInput multiline height={height} placeholderText={'Question 3'}/>
<TextInput multiline height={height} placeholderText={'Question 4'}/>
<TextInput multiline height={height} placeholderText={'Question 5'}/>
<TextInput multiline height={height} placeholderText={'Question 6'}/>
```

These textinput fields are dynamically created based on array

Answer (score 0):

I would write conditions that set the height based on the string length.

Like so :

Create a custom componentL

```js
  const CustomInput = ({question}) => {
    
    const[height,setHeight]=useState(5)
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(')
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if(response.length < 10) setHeight(5)
      if(response.length > 10 && textHeight < 20) setHeight(10)
      if(response.length > 20 && textHeight < 30) setHeight(30)
    },[height])
    
    return (<TextInput 
    multiline 
    onChange={(e) => setResponse(e)}
    height={height} 
    placeholderText={'Question 1'}
    />)
     }
```

And then in the parent component:

```js
const arrayOfQuestion = ['Question1','Question2','Question3','Question4']

    const ParentComponent = () => { 

      return (
         <View style={yourStyle}>
            {arrayOfQuestion.map((q, i) => {
               return CustomInput key={i} question={q}  /> 
             })}
         </View>
        )
      }
```

(Putting index as a key for a mapped element will work but is not a good practice. Find something unique instead, like a question id if your backend sends one)

Comment: For multiple text input fields which are dynamically generated..

Comment: Then create a custom input component and include those conditions in the logic.

Comment: Where are you stuck ? Can you share a piece of code ?

Comment: I have added some code for reference please see